# Access directive from the same scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a custom directive with method defined:

```
app.directive('modal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="modal" ng-show="visible">modal box</div>',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.visible = false;
      scope.show = function () {
        this.visible = true;
      };
      scope.close = function () {
        this.visible = false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

I'm using it like:

```
<button ng-click="modal.show()">Show modal</button>
<modal></modal>
```

However I cannot access this `modal` directive in the same scope.

I've tried with defined `id` attribute, like:

```
<button ng-click="myModal.show()">Show modal</button>
<modal id="myModal"></modal>
```

Is it even possible to access directive scope this way ?

Or better way would be do it using `$rootScope` or broadcasting events ?

I would like to not define this directive in controller - controller should not know about its existence.

Comment: Can you just try `ng-click='show()'`

Comment: @Chandermani Nothing happens.

Comment: That **scope** is your controllers scope in that case. There alternative ways for isolating the scope than your controller's scope. Check out under the **Isolating the Scope of a Directive** title of this guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @Chandermani Ok - in fact my scope was already isolated - that's why I couldn't call `show()`.

Comment: @nerezo Is it possible to access isolated scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a problem in your architecture. It's true that there are workarounds but they only make the problem more complicated.

If you look for a stable solution, check out the code for `$modal` in [Angular Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js). You will see they have `$modal` as a service.

The reasons are (for example) the following:

1. Opening and closing can be done from any scope
2. Template for the modal is separated from other code.

Answer (score 0):

Parent controllers have access to their child directives' scopes.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/sacavubeha/1/) I've created a small example to illustrate what I'm saying. Unless you have the scope attribute in your directive, it will use its parent's scope.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question - my scope is isolated. Can I access this isolated directive's scope from the controller's scope ?

Comment: Yup, you can bind to attributes in the directive. Like so: [link](http://jsbin.com/sacavubeha/1/). 
Also look [here](https://d2eip9sf3oo6c2.cloudfront.net/pdf/egghead-io-directive-definition-object-cheat-sheet.pdf?__vid=1f5b9b208cec01320f8322000b2a88d7) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with events:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = function(){
        $scope.$parent.$broadcast("show-modal");
    };

    $scope.hideModal = function(){
        $scope.$parent.$broadcast("hide-modal");
    };
}

myApp.directive('modal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="modal" ng-show="visible">modal box</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.visible = false;
      scope.$on('show-modal', function(){
          scope.visible = true;
      });

      scope.$on('hide-modal', function(){
          scope.visible = false;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Basically: broadcast an event (either 'show' or 'hide') from your controller, catch it inside the directive and do your logic.

And your html template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <button ng-click="showModal()">Show modal</button>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="hideModal()">Hide modal</button>
  <modal></modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'd like to avoid describing anything in the controller. It should not know about any directive inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your view might be like below:

```
<button ng-click="showModal()">Show modal</button>
<modal></modal>
```

You can put your methods to the $rootScope apart from the isolated scope. Only the template uses it's isolated scope and variables defined on it.

Here is a modified example:

```
app.directive('modal', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-show="visible">modal box</div>',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.visible = false;
            $rootScope.showModal = function () {
                console.log("showModal");
                scope.visible = true;
            };
            $rootScope.closeModal = function () {
                console.log("closeModal");
                scope.visible = false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```